# Can someone explain this word frequency count, please?

Tags: python, list, data-structures, word-frequency

I'm taking the MIT DS&A algorithm course and on the document distance problem, we have to parse a file into a list of words, then count the frequency of each word in the file. I have a hard time comprehending the following function:

```
def count_frequency(word_list):
    """
    Return a list giving pairs of form: (word,frequency)
    """
    L = []
    for new_word in word_list:
        for entry in L:
            if new_word == entry[0]:
                entry[1] = entry[1] + 1
                break
        else:
            L.append([new_word,1])
    return L
```

1. Why do we compare new_word to entry[0]?
   a. What if L is empty? What do we compare new_word to?
   b. Why do we compare new_word to entry[0] specifically? Why don't we do something like 
   `if new_word in L`
   c. Why do we need to use `break`?
2. Why is the `else` block 1 tab to the right of the earlier `if` block? When I tried to indent the `else` block, an indentation error would show up.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list `L` contains two-item entries due to `L.append([new_word,1])`.  If `L` is empty the `for` would not be entered, so there is no problem with `entry[0]`.

`entry[0]` is a word and `entry[1]` is a count.  You can't say `if new_word in L` because it is not just a list of strings.

`break` stops the `for` once a word is found.

`for/else` is a thing in Python.  The `else` runs if the `for` completes without interruption (a `break` in this case).  If `new_word` isn't in `L`, the `for` won't break and the new word and a count of 1 is added to `L`.

FYI, the built-in `collections.Counter()` would return similar results.

Comment: I did not know ```for/else``` is a thing, that confused me so much. I heard about the ```collections.Counter()``` but never had a chance to use it, I will definitely look into it. Thank you for you help!

Comment: hi Mark, can you explain to me what happens if the ```break``` statement was not there? To my understanding, the ```break``` statement prevents from iterating over the whole list L, hence makes the function more efficient. Without the ```break```, the function would still be correct, but less efficient, right?

Comment: @Jake yes, once you find a word in the list no need to check the rest of the list.  break leaves the inner `for` and the next `new_word` in the outer `for` will be processed.

Comment: You're awesome. Thank you!